# Is there any way to get Savings info of spot instance by AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli

I googled but can't find it. Can we obtain the spot usage and savings info in Savings tab on Spot instance by AWS CLI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

General pricing information is available via [Using the AWS Price List API - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html)

Current spot prices are available via [DescribeSpotPriceHistory - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSpotPriceHistory.html)

You would need to calculate the difference yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  Let met try this.